Metalic texture baking not working
I am trying to bake metalic texture using emit bake type. But the image texture coming as completely black. I have attached one screenshot for reference. If I am doing it wrong, kindly guide me.

I have added metalic to 1, still it is same, completely black.


What are you expecting to see? - You have metallic set to 0 on the BSDF shader and in any case the metallic is the same over the whole object so you won't see any change on the output image.

Even if I set it to 1, it also appeared completely black. I have attached an image for your reference.

it looks as if it doesn't work in Blender 4.2 for some reason. I checked it in a previous version before commenting and it was fine in that.

Ok I will check in different blender version.

In the shading tab you have to have the image texture node selected before you bake the texture. At least i think that could be your problem here.

I selected the image after that I baked it. I will be notified with an error if I do not select the image texture node.

try bake type glossy and not emit and uv unwrap your object.

tried glossy also still not working as expected.

I have followed this tutorial - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6BCgzi_db8g. Now I can bake metal texture.

I create one RGB node and set it to white.
Set metalic value to 0
Connect the RGB color attribute to Material output surface node.
Bake it with emit bake type



Since you use the Emit baking setting, you have to connect the input from the metallic image texture to the Colour input of the Emission section of the BDSFshader which you can get to by clicking the Emission dropdown.

Don't forget to reduce the Metallic setting to zero on the BDSF shader before baking.

I do not have that color option in principle BDSF node.

Did you click on the 'Emission' line on the BSDF shader to expand the panel? - The shader has changed a lot since Blender 4.0 and some of the settings are only visible if you expand the sections on it just as you do in other parts of Blender. See this tutorial for the changes.

Looking back through this question and the comments it doesn't look as if you've said whether you are following a tutorial or not. My comments are based on one of the YT tutorials such as this one. However that was done in Blender 3 with the earlier BSDF shader and why I added my answer showing where to find the setting in the later version.

You have to connect the color socket in the image to the metal conection of the PBR material. Right now it's not connected, so it can't work

I think it's worse than that, though that is a big problem. The metal texture itself is all black.
